# Remove Php Extention from URLs and convert querystring data with slash data

Tags: php

I’m trying to rewrite http://www.example.com/services.php?m=services&s=scan book&id=2 to http://www.example.com/services/services/scan-book/2 . I tried many ways and also tested above examples. But it is not ok yet. I encountered the following error.
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: You need to provide more information, for example which server are you using.

Answer (score 2):

Simple .htaccess example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^lookup/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /lookup.php?id=$1&view=$2
</IfModule>
```